# How to use urls instead of hashbangs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, express

I am building a web app with express.js in the back- and backbone.js in the front.end.

I want that the whole internall application is handled client side (backbone requests data and renders it, the server doesn't return any html directly).

To make ressources still accessable for bookmarks and third persons many javascript front-ends use hashbang.

I know would like to know if it also possible to use GET parameters (without hashbang) to do this (similar to the way how github handles the file browser)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML5 pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/) is what you are after. Not all browsers support it, there are libraries that can use hashes to add support for them.

Comment: Hi, does this also work for new users which visit the site the first time?